# If noun phrases can be genericised to ‘someone/something’, how are adjectives genericised?

Tags: generic-term, abstract-nouns

Often when you look up words in a dictionary, certain sentence patterns and collocations are often given in a kind of ‘genericised’ way, where animate noun phrases are replaced by *somebody* and inanimate ones by *something* (and verbal phrases usually by *do something*). For example, a definition of *help* might have the following:

> *[someone] helps [someone] [do something]*

– which can be turned into a ‘real’ sentence by replacing the ‘genericised placeholders’ with more meaningful phrases:

> [I] help [you] [clean your house]

I quite like this kind of ‘genericising’ and find it elegant and useful. However, *someone* and *something* here are used only for noun phrases (and verb phrases), and I haven’t been able to find a way of ‘genericising’ *adjectival phrases*. For example, a definition of *find* may have the following:

> *[someone] finds [somebody/something] **[adjective]***
>   => [I] find [it] [very interesting]

*Adjective* there doesn’t seem like a very good choice, since it just expresses a word class, not a ‘genericisation’—that is, it is the counterpart to ‘noun’, ‘verb’, rather than the counterpart to ‘someone’, ‘[do] something’.

***Is there an established way of ‘genericising’ adjectives that fits this general pattern?***

Comment: I see your dilemma here. The word usually used to mark that it represents an adjective/attribute in a genericised sentence pattern description is, unfortunately, ***something***, which rather clashes with the _something_ used to represent noun phrases. _Adjective_ is probably your best bet if you want to avoid that clash.

Comment: Also, your question was quite confusing in the way it was asked (and presented). I’m fairly sure I understand what you’re asking, but some parts of your question were not really related at all and just added confusion. I’ve taken the liberty of editing the question quite substantially to make it clearer what the crux of the question is.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what on earth the OP is asking about, and how his examples relate to it? I find the Title totally indecipherable, and the question no less so.

Comment: @Brian I’ve edited; I hope it’s clearer now. It’s actually a good question, just poorly presented.

Comment: I answered you before you edited your question. I'm wondering if you saw my answer. I don't see any other options other than your "adjective"

Comment: I originally down-voted and voted to close what I viewed as an indecipherable mess; thanks to @JanusBahsJacquet's patience and puzzle-solving abilities, I've now retracted both.

Comment: Nouns can be genericised  because they cannot take many forms in a sentence: they are either something or somebody. Adjectives can take many forms, from past participles, present participles, nominatives, predicatives, postpositives, comparatives, etc.  How can one take all of those things and distill them into one word and have that word fit a generic model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ***somehow*** as a generic placeholder in that case. It means "in some way or manner", which gets at what an adjective does while maintaining the *some-* concordance.

> [someone] finds [somebody/something] [*somehow*]

Comment: somehow is adverb. I need adjective

Comment: You could also try [some way]. Don't be too literal-minded about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ideas maybe:

- to find somebody / something something
- to find somebody / something anything
- to find somebody / something possible
- to find somebody / something likely
- to find somebody / something attribute

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a totally generic form, because there are so many different ways that adjectives are used. So you're more likely to use a fairly specific category word that's appropriate for the specific context:

> [someone] finds a [color] [something]

Another possibility is that *[something]* doesn't necessarily stand for a noun, but a noun phrase, which can include adjectives and prepositional phrases. So the adjectives are already implicitly allowed, and don't need to be shown explicitly in the template.